# Problema com jogo de adivinhação de número

Tags: python, python-3.x

Esse script de um jogo de advinhação de número não funciona, na parte `if z = "s"` o Python diz que a sintaxe é inválida. Alguém poderia me dizer por que isso não funciona, e qual seria o correto?

```
import random
def rerun():
    if z = "s"
        numero_aleatorio= random.randint(1,10)
        x = numero_aleatorio
        y = input("Advinhe o numero ")
        y = int(y)
        if y > x:
            y = int(input("Numero muito alto! "))
            while y > x:
                y = int(input("Numero muito alto! "))
                if y == x:
                    print("Voce advinhou!")
                    z = input("Você quer continuar jogando?(s/n) ")
                elif y < x:
                y = int(input("Numero muito baixo! "))
            while y < x:
                y = int(input("Numero muito baixo! "))
                if y == x:
                    print("Voce advinhou!")
                    z = input("Você quer continuar jogando?(s/n) ")
                     if z == "s":
                         rerun()
                     if z == "n":
                         quit()
numero_aleatorio= random.randint(1,10)
x = numero_aleatorio
y = input("Advinhe o numero ")
y = int(y)
if y > x:
    y = int(input("Numero muito alto! "))
    while y > x:
            y = int(input("Numero muito alto! "))
            if y == x:
                print("Voce advinhou!")
                z = input("Você quer continuar jogando?(s/n) ")
                    rerun()
elif y < x:
    y = int(input("Numero muito baixo! "))
    while y < x:
            y = int(input("Numero muito baixo! "))
            if y == x:
                print("Voce advinhou!")
                z = input("Você quer continuar jogando?(s/n) ")
                    rerun()
```

---

Tentei também com o código assim:

```
import random
def rerun():
    if z == "s":
        numero_aleatorio= random.randint(1,10)
        x = numero_aleatorio
        y = input("Advinhe o numero ")
        y = int(y)
        if y > x:
            y = int(input("Numero muito alto! "))
            while y > x:
                y = int(input("Numero muito alto! "))
                if y == x:
                    print("Voce advinhou!")
                    z = input("Você quer continuar jogando?(s/n) ")
                elif y < x:
                    y = int(input("Numero muito baixo! "))
            while y < x:
                y = int(input("Numero muito baixo! "))
                if y == x:
                    print("Voce advinhou!")
                    z = input("Você quer continuar jogando?(s/n) ")
                    if z == "s":
                         rerun()
                    if z == "n":
                         quit()
numero_aleatorio= random.randint(1,10)
x = numero_aleatorio
y = input("Advinhe o numero ")
y = int(y)
if y > x:
    y = int(input("Numero muito alto! "))
    while y > x:
            y = int(input("Numero muito alto! "))
            if y == x:
                print("Voce advinhou!")
                z = input("Você quer continuar jogando?(s/n) ")
                rerun()
elif y < x:
    y = int(input("Numero muito baixo! "))
    while y < x:
            y = int(input("Numero muito baixo! "))
            if y == x:
                print("Voce advinhou!")
                z = input("Você quer continuar jogando?(s/n) ")
                rerun()
```

Mas agora dá o erro abaixo, após o usuário selecionar se quer continuar jogando ou não:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/chlav/Documents/Python scripts/advinhar.py", line 45, in <module>
    rerun()
  File "C:/Users/chlav/Documents/Python scripts/advinhar.py", line 3, in rerun
    if z == "s":
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'z' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Faltou um `:` no no final da linha que está dando erro, e como é uma comparação, precisa de `==`...

Comment: Mesmo assim continua com o mesmo erro...

Comment: Carlos Henrique o correto seria `if z == 's':` na terceira linha do seu script.

Comment: Em Python `=` é atribuição, para teste de igualdade use `==`.

Comment: Eu arrumei isso e alguns parágrafos que estavam dando erro e agora ficou assim

Comment: Apareceu outro erro?

Comment: Sim, já editei o post

Comment: evita o uso de variaveis globais... tira a comparação de dentro da função e joga ela pro escopo global... vc ta usando a mesma a variavel global z dentro da função e fazendo uma comparação esperando q ela seja o z global. mas como vc tem outro z dentro do escopo da função ele tenta pegar o z local e da um erro de sintaxe

Comment: Mas então como eu faço o jogo reiniciar?

Comment: Teria de ser usado um laço de repetição.

Comment: Pesquise no Google sobre Escopo de variáveis em Python e você vai entender o erro do seu código

Answer (score 2):

Não é necessário repetir todo o código duas vezes só para fazer recomeçar. Ao invés disso use um laço de repetição como o `while` para repetir uma parte do código usando uma condição:

```
import random

opcao = "s"
while opcao == "s":
    numero_aleatorio = random.randint(1,10)
    tentativa = int(input("Advinhe o numero:"))
    while tentativa != numero_aleatorio:
        if tentativa < numero_aleatorio:
            print("Numero muito baixo")
        else:
            print("Numero muito alto")           
        tentativa = int(input("Advinhe o numero:"))
    print("Voce advinhou!")
    opcao = input("Você quer continuar jogando?")
```

Nesse exemplo, para sair da repeticão, é necessário que a condição `opcao ==  "s"` seja quebrada, isso ocorrerá quando o usuário entrar outra letra diferente no `input()` do final.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia. Voce ja tem uma resposta, mas ainda assim gostaria de esclarecer o que houve com seu código.

Um professor me ensinou que em Python, estamos escrevendo uma carta em inglês pro computador.
O Resultado do seu erro foi: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'z' referenced before assignment".
Entao, se traduzirmos: "Erro Local Não Vinculado: variável local 'z' referenciada antes da atribuição"

Devido a esse erro, acredito que o seu `z` nao seja uma variável global. Ou seja 
**ele teve ter sido declarado, dentro de outro def**
O que nos joga para a regra do encapsulamento.

Possivelmente seu problema deve ser resolvido voce deve tornar o `z` uma variável global.

```
global z   # Colocar isso aqui, antes do seu if, pode resolver o problema.
if z == "s":
    numero_aleatorio= random.randint(1,10)
    x = numero_aleatorio
    y = input("Advinhe o numero ")
    y = int(y)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma das principais dicas está na [resposta do @nosklo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/362604/112052): você está repetindo código sem necessidade, sendo que poderia usar um *loop* (é para isso que os *loops* servem, para executar alguma coisa repetidas vezes).

Outro detalhe é que tem variáveis a mais que não seriam necessárias. Por exemplo, quando você faz isso:

```
numero_aleatorio= random.randint(1,10)
x = numero_aleatorio
```

Você cria o `numero_aleatorio` e depois só usa ele para atribuir seu valor em `x` (e depois disso ele não é mais usado). Não tem motivo para criar duas variáveis para isso, use somente uma delas. E no caso, eu escolheria usar somente `numero_aleatorio`, por ser um nome melhor do que `x`, já que indica exatamente o que aquela variável significa.

Isso vale para outras variáveis também. `y` e `z` são nomes "genéricos" demais e quem vê o código não consegue perceber o que elas significam (a menos que leia o código todo, claro). Pode parecer um detalhe bobo, mas dar nomes significativos para tudo (variáveis, funções, classes, etc) torna todo o processo de programar mais fácil, pois você não precisa ficar toda hora lembrando "O que é esse `x` mesmo?" (já se você ler `numero_aleatorio`, saberá imediatamente o que ele significa).

Dito isso, a [solução proposta pelo @nosklo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/362604/112052) já simplifica bastante o seu código. Veja como você pode chamar `int(input(...))` diretamente, já guardando o valor numérico na variável, e veja também como o `while` já elimina a necessidade de repetir o código, e a verificação do valor digitado é simplificada com apenas um `if`/`else` dentro de outro `while`.

---

Eu ainda proponho mais algumas modificações. Se quiser, nem precisa da variável para guardar a opção de sair ou não do jogo, pois também dá para fazer assim:

```
while True:
    # lê a tentativa, verifica se está certa, etc
    ....

    # se a opção não for "s", sai do "while True"
    if input("Você quer continuar jogando? (s/n)") != 's':
        break
```

O `while True` indica que o *loop* vai rodar indefinidamente. Mas se a opção digitada for diferente de `'s'`, é chamado o `break`, [que interrompe o `while`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break).

A menos que você vá usar a opção digitada para mais alguma coisa, não precisa guardá-la em uma variável. Mas se você quiser usar uma variável para isso, chame-a de `opcao` ou algum outro nome significativo, em vez de `z` ou qualquer outro nome "genérico" que não diz nada sobre a sua função no código.

Outra sugestão é verificar o valor digitado. Você está pegando um valor digitado com [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) e em seguida usando [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) para tentar converter para um número. Só que o usuário pode digitar qualquer coisa, inclusive algo que não é um número, então seria interessante verificar isso também, ficando com um código mais ou menos assim:

```
while True:
    try:
        # lê o valor e tenta converter para número
        tentativa = int(input("Adivinhe o número:"))
        break # se chegou aqui, é porque int() funcionou
    except ValueError:
        # se int() falhou, é porque não foi digitado um número, então tente novamente
        print("Digite um número válido")
```

Se o `int()` falhar (porque não foi digitado um número), ocorrerá um `ValueError`, e neste caso, o código dentro do `except` será executado. No caso, eu informo o que aconteceu, e como estou dentro de um `while`, será lido outro número.

Mas como no código estamos lendo a tentativa duas vezes (uma antes de verificar se o número foi adivinhado, e outra depois, caso não tenha sido), é melhor encapsular toda esta lógica de ler o número em uma função. O código final fica assim:

```
import random

# função que lê o número e retorna o valor lido
def ler_numero(mensagem):
    while True:
        try:
            # lê o número e retorna o valor
            return int(input(mensagem))
        except ValueError:
            # se não foi digitado um número, int() lança um ValueError
            print("Digite um número válido")


while True:
    numero_aleatorio = random.randint(1, 10)

    tentativa = ler_numero("Advinhe o numero:")
    while tentativa != numero_aleatorio:
        if tentativa < numero_aleatorio:
            print("Numero muito baixo")
        else:
            print("Numero muito alto")

        tentativa = ler_numero("Advinhe o numero:")

    print("Voce advinhou!")

    # se a opção não for "s", sai do "while True"
    if input("Você quer continuar jogando? (s/n)") != 's':
        break
```

Repare que dentro da função `ler_numero` eu usei `return` em vez de `break`. É que se `int()` funcionar (ou seja, foi digitado um número e este foi convertido corretamente), eu já posso retornar o seu valor imediatamente (não precisa ter um `break` para sair do `while` e depois ter um `return`).

Já se o `int()` falhar, eu caio no bloco `except`, a mensagem informa que o valor digitado não é um número e o `while` continua executando, pedindo que seja digitado outro número.